# Reusable button directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Reusable button directive not working ,

Here i am created reusable button directive , in below my code static button is working , but dynamic (directive ) button is not working. please check the below code

Thanks for your help

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', [ ]);
  
app.directive('telSavebutton', function() {
  return{
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button type="submit" ng-click="testcontroller()" >directive button</button>',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
          onSubmit: '&',
          likeClick: '&'    
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes){
          scope.submit = function(){
              scope.onSubmit();
          }
      }
  }
});  
   
app.controller('testCntler', ['$scope', '$location',  function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.testcontroller=function()
  {
    alert("Working")
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@~1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15"
        src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" data-ng-app="testApp"  > 

<form novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()"
      ng-controller="testCntler" >
    
    <table width="293" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="127">First Name</td>
        <td width="150"> <input type="text"  ng-model="fname" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mid Name</td>
        <td> <input type="text"  ng-model="mName" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td> <input type="text"  ng-model="lName" ></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <button type="submit"
            ng-click="testcontroller()" >Static button</button> 
        <tel-Savebutton   check-Id="firstName" ></tel-Savebutton></td>
       </tr>    
    </table>   
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `telSavebutton` directive has isolate scope, but you're using a function `testcontroller()` in that directive's template--which is in the Controller's scope.

Fix it by first altering your your template:

```
template: '<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" >directive button</button>',
```

And by passing in a function as an attribute of the directive instance:

```
<tel-savebutton on-submit="testcontroller"></tel-savebutton></td>
```

Comment: Cool! Angular Directives were really hard to learn at first, but after some experience they will be second nature. I especially found [this talk](https://youtu.be/UMkd0nYmLzY) to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

change ng-click="testcontroller()" in your directive:

```
template: '<button type="submit" ng-click="onFormSubmit()" >directive button</button>'
```

and add on-submit in html:

```
<tel-Savebutton check-Id="firstName" on-form-submit="testcontroller()"></tel-Savebutton></td>
```

Also change scope reference:

```
scope: {
        onFormSubmit: '&'        
    },
```